# Pharo/Squeak - How do I quickly browse the implementation of a given method in a given class?

Tags: ide, smalltalk, squeak, pharo, class-hierarchy

Let's say I want to see how "copy" is implemented in the Dictionary class. Currently I use the system browser and manually traverse the inheritance hierarchy (bottom up) until I find the class that implements the given message. Is there a one-liner for the workspace, that would open the system browser at the right location?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
( SomeClass whichClassIncludesSelector: #initialize ) browse
```

That will browse the class that implements the message #initialize.

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I just type the #selector in a workspace, highlight it, and hit alt+m to pull up all implementors of the message.  Much faster than typing all that code.

Answer (score 2):

(SomeClass>>#someSelector) browse

works as well in my Pharo image.

works as well in my Pharo image.
And since you want to find a class first, you can combine it with previous example..

((SomeSubclass whichClassIncludesSelector: #someSelector)>>#someSelector) browse

to directly go to given method.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using OmniBrowser, you can use the contextual menu *Implementors in Hierarchy...* to only browse the implementors of a selector in the hierarchy of the `Dictionary`.

OmniBrowser also provides an *Inheritance Browser*. Select any implementation of `#copy` and click on the `Inheritance` button in the toolbar. It will show you a hierarchical view of all implementors of `#copy`.